# font embed restriction in PDF

Tags: embedded-fonts

I'm stuck in a problem, the font I want to use can't save in pdf, STHeiti and STXihei they are both the default Chinese fonts in Mac os.
[image]

illustrator give me this error, I don't know how to change the font to make this work,
I know a software in windows named Font Creator that looks promising, But I don't know exactly how to use it

Comment: First, have you read that message? Basically it says that you're not allowed to embed that font. So, are you asking us to show you a way to break the law?

Answer (score 3):

This is a licensing restriction imposed by the distributor of this font, there is no way to legally embed it in a PDF.